# two divs inside a container ovelayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container DIV that has two DIVs inside. The first DIV (my-canvas) needs to be positioned absoulte at 0 0 inside the container. I want the second DIV to take up the remaining 50% of space below. The finished product needs to be responsive. I am stuck on how to position the second DIV.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container map-container">
    @include('maps.world-map')
    <div id="my-canvas"></div>
    <div id="their-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.map-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

#my-canvas,
#their-canvas {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 540px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 999998;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#my-canvas {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

I am trying to figure out the CSS for the canvas below

```
#their-canvas {
  ????
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In fixed width overlapping or responsive design?

Comment: Hi @Santhoshkumar I am looking for both divs to overlay on the parent container with each div being half of the area. I also want the divs to adjust their height based on changing browser width

Comment: Hi @TheRealPapa i added answer, please check it...

Answer (score 1):

You can set second div using `botton:0px, height: 50%;`. check updated snippet below

```js
$('.map-container').height($(window).height()-55);
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.map-container').height($(window).height()-55);
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.map-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;

}

#my-canvas,
#their-canvas {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 540px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 999998;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#my-canvas {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
#their-canvas {
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container map-container">
    <div id="my-canvas">my-canvas</div>
    <div id="their-canvas">their-canvas</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Super User, your suggestion works but on changing browser width the div heights does not change according to the parent's changing height. So it is not responsive as is.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "it needs to be responsive".

But if you want to put your second canvas below, you can set a `top: 50%;` property. Since you are using relative values for the `height` and `top` of your canvas, its parent needs to have a defined `height` or `min-height`

See https://jsfiddle.net/NotANumber/3k2go0qf/

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, Using CSS itself you can achieve,

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.map-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  height:100%;
}

#my-canvas,
#their-canvas {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 540px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 999998;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#my-canvas {
  background: red;
}
#their-canvas {
  bottom: 0px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container map-container">
    <div id="my-canvas"></div>
    <div id="their-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi SantoshKumar, the divs need to be placed in an absolute position over the top of their container. Thanks for helping out